# How do I get Django REST Framework to generate a schema with a different base API URL?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

After upgrading one of my existing projects to Django REST Framework 3.4 I am attempting to use the `coreapi` CLI client to interact with my API. However, I am having problems fetching, creating, or updating resources because all the schema-generated API URLs map to the base URL of my application `/` instead of the base URL for my application's API, which is `/api/v2/`.

To get the URLs in the generated schema to output with the `/api/v2/` prefix should I be changing something with my URL configuration and/or my router, or should I be using a custom schema generator as described in the [Django REST Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#using-schemagenerator)?

Here is a sample of the schema output (from a request to `/api/v2/` with the header `Accept:application/vnd.coreapi+json`):

```
{
    "_type": "document",
    "_meta": {
        "title": "My API v2"
    },
    "categories": {
        "create": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/categories/",
            "action": "post",
            "encoding": "application/json",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "title",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "form"
                }
            ]
        },
        "destroy": {
            "_type": "link",
            "url": "/categories/{pk}/",
             "action": "delete",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "pk",
                    "required": true,
                    "location": "path"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Here is how the routers are setup in `app/api_v2/api.py`:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from app.api_v2 import viewsets

api_v2 = DefaultRouter(schema_title='My API v2')
api_v2.register(r'categories', viewsets.CategoryViewSet)
...
```

My `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings is configured to `ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'`, and `myproject/urls.py` is defined as follows:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

import app.views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Finally, `app/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from app.api_v2.api import api_v2

import app.views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/v2/', include(api_v2.urls)),
    ...
]
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you resolve yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an issue with versions <=3.4.

It is resolved in the current master.

See also https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4401